# Use react "runtime": "automatic" with flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env", 
        ["@babel/preset-react", {
            "runtime": "automatic"
        }],
        "@babel/preset-flow"
    ]
}
```

Above you can see my `.bablerc` file , I try to setup oportunity create components without including `React` import on the top of it . But `flow` has own opinion on it and return warning `Cannot resolve name React. [cannot-resolve-name]`. What should I do in this way ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add to your `.flowconfig` options

```
react.runtime=automatic
```

It's documented [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-react-runtime-automatic-classic)

Comment: yes, works , thanks , also someone can check it here https://flow.org/en/docs/react/

Comment: You're welcome :D If you can also mark this as the accepted answer that can help others easily find the answer in the future